# What are web development services?

Tags: web, service

Me and my Lab partner are supposed to develop an online shopping website for an imaginary client.

We are also supposed to provide a summary of web development services we are providing to our client.

The question is, what are web development services? Please leave us a simple explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually most of the web development companies provides different kind of services to their Clients that cater B2B and B2C Customers through Solutions
Some of the example services include

1. E-Commerce Applications
2. Educational Applications
3. Discussion Forums
4. Single Page Web Applications
5. Social Networking Sites
6. Content Management Systems etc.

Above are just some of the many services provided by a web development companies. You can also showcase your skill set and other features saying that 
why should a client opt for you.

Try to visit different Web Development companies sites and read the services they provide for better understanding of the kinds of services that are available.